# What is the difference between 16-slim, 16-jdk-slim, 16-ea-slim docker images

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, java-16

What is the difference between the following Docker images?

- `openjdk:16-slim`
- `openjdk:16-jdk-slim`
- `openjdk:16-ea-slim`

Which is smaller in size and can be used in a Spring Boot project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is in the Java version used and hence in the compressed size (links below):

- [openjdk:16-slim](https://hub.docker.com/layers/openjdk/library/openjdk/16-slim/images/sha256-489741bb324b3d6a12e642a5823fcc69a42423adbcfd8c9dd4514fa8720344e3) of compressed size `198.93 MB` uses `16.0.1`
- [openjdk:16-jdk-slim](https://hub.docker.com/layers/openjdk/library/openjdk/16-jdk-slim/images/sha256-489741bb324b3d6a12e642a5823fcc69a42423adbcfd8c9dd4514fa8720344e3) of compressed size `198.93 MB` uses `16.0.1`
- [openjdk:16-ea-slim](https://hub.docker.com/layers/openjdk/library/openjdk/16-ea-slim/images/sha256-afa1520df6d94352447e778a13f4af83e34d6433947d28edd517a632d43b96c7) of compressed size `198.82 MB` uses `16-ea+34` (early-access)

You correctly noticed there is no difference between `openjdk:16-slim` and `openjdk:16-jdk-slim` aside from hashes. I assume there are two identical images in order to respect the new naming conventions (my guess).

If you refer to the [openjdk DockerHub description | Image Variants](https://hub.docker.com/_/openjdk?tab=description&page=1&ordering=last_updated), you might find the following:

> The openjdk images come in many flavors, each designed for a specific use case.
>
> #### openjdk:<version>
>
> This is the defacto image. If you are unsure about what your needs are, you probably want to use this one. It is designed to be used both as a throw away container (mount your source code and start the container to start your app), as well as the base to build other images off of.

**Important:** If you decide to use Spring Boot with Java 16, you need to use currently the newest version (as of May, 2021) of Spring Boot [`2.5.0`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter/2.5.0) or newer. Read more at [Spring Boot 2.5 is now GA](https://spring.io/blog/2021/05/20/spring-boot-2-5-is-now-ga).